# For loop to iterate through the URLs in a dataframe and save images in destination folder

Tags: python, for-loop

I was trying to use for loop in python to iterate through the urls stored in the dataframe and save images in destination folder. Below is the code I have written however unable to generate any result. Can anybody help me fine tune this code to get desired results without using any other library.

```
df=ad_url_list #this contains the urls
for url in df:
    i=0
    r= requests.get(url[i], allow_redirects=True) #to fetch the first url from df
    open(url[i][-36:],'wb').write(r.content) # name the image file as per last 36 objects in any url 
    i=i+1  #iterating with an increment of 1 to move to next url
```

Comment: some print statements might help you ... what does it do instead of what you think it should  do? maybe try `for url in df['url']` its hard to say without seeing your code... but i assume that `for url in df` is just iterating the column names

Comment: Did you read in Docs how to use for loops? Did you search on internet, how to index iteration using for loops?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. This is resolved now and I am able to save the images successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop as is simply iterates through your dataframe's column headers (if it is a pandas dataframe).  It might be better to obtain the length of the dataframe, and iterate through each row using .`iloc` instead.

```
df = ad_url_list
for i in range(0, len(df)-1):
    url = df.iloc[i, 0] # replace 0 with your desired column index
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    filename = url[-36:]
    open(filename, 'wb').write(r.content)
```

If your `df` variable is in fact not a dataframe, but a list, you can try this:

```
df = ad_url_list
for url in df:
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    filename = url[-36:]
    open(filename, 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However even after running this getting the below error - ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-3bebe4de41b5> in <module>
      1 df=ad_url_list
      2 for i in range(0,len(df)-1):
----> 3     url = df.iloc[i,0]
      4     r= requests.get(url[i], allow_redirects=True)
      5     filename = url[-36:]

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Comment: So it is not a dataframe, but rather a list.  Updated my answer, though without seeing what your data looks like, I can't guarantee it will work.

Comment: 2nd code worked since my dataframe was containing the urls as list items. Successfully able to save the images in directory after running this. Thanks so much.

Comment: My pleasure, mind selecting it as the accepted answer?

Comment: Not at all, could you please guide how to select this response as accepted answer, unable to see any option...also I am new to this forum hence need some guidance.

Comment: Sure please see here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers